# not set page title

Tags: google-analytics, url, page, title-attribute

I am seeing on GA4 a lot of traffic on a "not set" page title.

I'll explain the whole situation to you:

In my company, the marketing team wants to track how many people apply to our available jobs. BUT, all the jobs page has the same url. For instance, the page where you apply to the data analyst job, and the page where you apply for front-end have the same URL.

What I thought was that we could differentiate the pages by page title.

Problem: In GA4 explorations, I was testing this possibility (differentiate by page title), it works, but I have a lot of traffic assigned to "not set" page title. How will I know what page has that much traffic, since the URL is the same for all pages?

I hope someone can help me.
I am sorry if my explanation is confusing.

PS: We cannot add utm parameters to the url, because (I think) the platform where they manage the job application doesn't have that feature.

Thank you

Comment: How are you deploying GA4? Google Tag Manager or some other tag management application?